# How to correctly install ffmpeg inside dokku container on digitalocean?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, digital-ocean, dokku

I created a droplet on DO with installed Dokku, then I created an app and its uses the [videoshow](https://github.com/h2non/videoshow). This lib using ffmpeg. I tried to add heroku ffmpeg buildpacks, but always without success.I always see in the logs: `Error: Cannot find ffmpeg`.

How correctly can i install the ffmpeg inside dokku-app (container) ?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to `dokku run <appname> ffmpeg -version` with ffmpeg buildpack ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `videoshow` documentation :

> If you want to use videoshow in Heroku, you could use the ffmpeg2 buildpack

Dokku work like Heroku thanks to `herokuish` lib, so here the correct ffmpeg buildpack :
https://github.com/h2non/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg2